# creating messages that appear after content is created

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to create an a message to appear with a link to the content when the new content is created

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Quick answer - check out the rules module. Hopefully someone else can explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [RULES](https://drupal.org/project/rules) you can achieve it, as suggested by ROOBY

- Create new RULE

  [image]
- Add action

  [image]

  [image]
- Create Node view link

  [image]

Comment: Is there anyway to make [node:url] a clickable link

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with some code in a custom module:

```
hook_node_insert($node) {
    if($node->type=='my_content_type') {
        drupal_set_message(t('New content created: :link', array(':link' => l($node->title, 'node/'.$node->nid))));
    }
}
```